# Kotlin Native Compilation Time

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm new to Kotlin Native, I just did a 'Hello World' and it took about 4s to compile, so I have the following questions:

- is this normal or there is something wrong with my system?
- is Kotlin Native production ready?

```kotlin
fun main() {
        print("hello world")
}
```

```sh
kotlinc-native SampleLinux.kt -o hello
```

btw I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 / 16GB ram / iCore 5

Thanks

Comment: 4s is not the fastest compilation time but also not the slowest. Also hello world is not the best test case for it. Example with couple thousands lines will be much better. And no, kotlin native is very far from being production ready. (checked last month)

Comment: For me it takes [7.11 seconds](https://imgur.com/a/m4POWSF) @ Ryzen 5 4500u 8GB, Its even slower than yours :)

Comment: While its taking 234 ms as compiling from Intellij, probably because cached builds are faster.